# How can I recover 1 year of chat history from Skype online severs?

Tags: skype

I want to recover 1 year of chat history from Skype. 
My Skype application goes to 3 months of history only. 
How can I go further back to 1 year?

Comment: You need to set the settings in Skype like how many months or days you want to keep the data you can set it as forever also. May i know did you set this before.

Comment: If you done this you can retrieve the data from your HDD.